# Создание таблицы стилями CSS - строки получаются разной ширины

Tags: css

Пишу таблицу стилями
Код страницы

```css
.priceblock {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.pricelist {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.itemstring {
  width: 100%;
}

.itemname,
.itemmodel,
.itemprice,
.itemavailability,
.itemdescription {
  border: solid 0px #bbb;
}

.itemname {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #aba;
}

.itemmodel {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #acc;
}

.itemdescription {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #a12;
}

.itemoffer {}

.itemprice {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #afc;
}

.itemavailability {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceblock">
  <div class="pricelist">
    <div class="itemstring">
      <div class="itemname">Наименование</div>
      <div class="itemmodel">Тип</div>
      <div class="itemdescription">Описание</div>
      <div class="itemprice">Цена</div>
      <div class="itemavailability">Наличие</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricelist">
    <div class="itemstring">
      <div class="itemname">Наименование Наименование Наименование Наименование </div>
      <div class="itemmodel"> Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип </div>
      <div class="itemdescription">Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание </div>
      <div class="itemprice">Цена</div>
      <div class="itemavailability">Наличие</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Результат - при заполнении таблицы - колонки разных строк получаются разной ширины, и вся таблица тоже.

Почему - не могу понять. Подскажите.

Comment: Это стандартное поведение табличных свойств. В вашем случае проще на flexbox переписать. `.itemstring {display: flex;}`  и чтобы ширина корректно указывалась `.itemstring > div {flex: none;}`

Answer (score 4):

```
.itemstring {
  width: 100%;

  display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```css
.priceblock {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.pricelist {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.itemstring {
  width: 100%;
  
  display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.itemname,
.itemmodel,
.itemprice,
.itemavailability,
.itemdescription {
  border: solid 0px #bbb;
}

.itemname {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #aba;
}

.itemmodel {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #acc;
}

.itemdescription {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #a12;
}

.itemoffer {}

.itemprice {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #afc;
}

.itemavailability {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceblock">
  <div class="pricelist">
    <div class="itemstring">
      <div class="itemname">Наименование</div>
      <div class="itemmodel">Тип</div>
      <div class="itemdescription">Описание</div>
      <div class="itemprice">Цена</div>
      <div class="itemavailability">Наличие</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricelist">
    <div class="itemstring">
      <div class="itemname">Наименование Наименование Наименование Наименование </div>
      <div class="itemmodel"> Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип Тип </div>
      <div class="itemdescription">Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание </div>
      <div class="itemprice">Цена</div>
      <div class="itemavailability">Наличие</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в стили:

```
.itemstring > div{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: По ширине выровнялись, но появилась другая проблема, высота ячейки с большим количеством текста - наибольшая. Остальные ячейки - меньше по высоте. Изначально идея была в том, чтобы оформление было как в таблице.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, пока решил таким образом '.pricelist:first-child > .itemstring > div { float:left;} '